# How to insert floats two decimal points in list box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using three variables (a = 10.00, b = 20.89, c = 30.90) and insert their values in Multilistbox but Multilistbox gets their values (10.0, 20.89, 30.9). that's why I add `"{:.2f}".format` but I got the following error :

```
total = sum(self.lists[-1].get(0, END))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

In my case {:.2f}".format did not work.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk


class MultiListbox(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(sticky="nsew")
        self.select_index = None
        i = 2
        for num, (l, w) in enumerate(lists):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(num, weight=w, uniform='fred')
            i += num
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.lists = []

        for num, (l, w) in enumerate(lists):
            frame = Frame(self, borderwidth=0)
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            frame.grid(row=1, column=num, sticky="nsew")
            Label(frame, text=l, font=("Vrinda (Body CS)", 11), borderwidth=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor="center", justify="center").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            lb = Listbox(frame, font=("Vrinda (Body CS)", 9), height=5, borderwidth=1, selectborderwidth=1, exportselection=FALSE)
            lb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.lists.append(lb)
            lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<B2-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('&lt;Button-4>', lambda e, s=self: s._scroll(SCROLL, 1, PAGES))
            lb.bind('&lt;Button-5>', lambda e, s=self: s._scroll(SCROLL, -1, PAGES))
            lb.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)

        sb_y = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=self._yscroll)
        sb_y.grid(row=1, rowspan=2, column=i, sticky="nsew")
        self.lists[0]['yscrollcommand'] = sb_y.set

        ent_total = Entry(self, width=0, justify="center")
        ent_total.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nesw")
        ent_total.insert(0, "Total")

        self.sum_value = StringVar(value=0)
        ent_sum_value = Entry(self, width=0, textvariable=self.sum_value)
        ent_sum_value.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nesw")

        sb_x = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self._xscroll)
        sb_x.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=i, sticky="ew")
        self.lists[0]['xscrollcommand'] = sb_x.set

    def _select(self, y):
        row = self.lists[0].nearest(y)
        self.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.selection_set(row)
        return 'break'

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_mark(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _yscroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.yview(*args)

    def _xscroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.xview(*args)

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for l in self.lists:
            result.append(l.get(first,last))
        if last: return list(map(*[None] + result))
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for e in elements:
            i = 0
            for l in self.lists:
                l.insert(index, e[i])
                i = i + 1
        self.sum_values()

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        self.select_index =[first]
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_set(first, last)

    def sum_values(self):
        total = sum(self.lists[-1].get(0, END))
        self.sum_value.set(total)

    def OnMouseWheel(self, event):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.yview("scroll", event.delta,"units")
        # this prevents default bindings from firing, which
        # would end up scrolling the widget twice
        return "break"


class FormAddProduct:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = master
        self.frame.configure(padx=5)
        for i in range(0, 1):
            self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid_rowconfigure (1, weight = 1)
        self._init_widgets()

    def _init_widgets(self):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.frame, relief=FLAT, borderwidth=1)
        for i in range(0, 1):
            self.frame1.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        for i in range(0, 1):
            self.frame1.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.mlb = MultiListbox(self.frame1,(
            ('SL.', 1), ('Particulars', 3), ('Amount $', 1)))
        self.mlb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        a = "{:.2f}".format(10.00)
        b = 20.89
        c = 30.90
        a1 = (1, "Apple", a)
        b1 = (2, "Orange", b)
        c1 = (3, "Orange", c)

        self.mlb.insert(END, a1)
        self.mlb.insert(END, b1)
        self.mlb.insert(END, c1)
        self.frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=5)

def main():
    app = tk.Tk()
    FormAddProduct(app)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please post the part of code, that is important only

Comment: What have you done to debug this? For example, have you verified that `self.lists[-1].get(0, END)` is returning what you think it should return? You say you get an error when applying formatting, but the code you say causes the error doesn't use formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal representation showing less decimals shouldn't be of issue, it's showing you 10.0 because 10.00 conveys no extra meaning, even though internally it still supports decimal precision. You should remove the string formatting and just leave it be, only formatting it when you want to output it to console or display it somewhere. Ideally tkinter should have a way to specify decimal format in their API

Remember that when you're maintaining an internal state for numeric values, they should always be float so that numeric operations can be performed without running into such errors. Whenever these numbers need to be displayed then you can format it the way you wish. As for the error:-

Strings can't be added to numbers as it's not clear whether you want to add numbers or concatenate two strings. (str + str and number + number are both valid operations that do two different things) :